# Export and upload a key from a Java keystore No key for alias

Tags: java, android, google-play, keystore

I'm trying to use the App signing from google play console, I'm using the script that google provides:

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a
```

replacing with the correct keystore and alias I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: No key for alias:

But I'm 100% sure that the alias is correct, because I can generate the signed bundle/APK from android studio using the same alias, the same key, and still when I run the scrpit from google it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

Also spent too long trying to fix this. To make sure you are using the correct alias, go to the directory where your `foo.keystore` is located and enter the command: `keytool -v -list -keystore foo.keystore`

Enter your password for the keystore then it will show you the correct alias.

Use this in script:
`java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=<your-alias> --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=<your-encyption-key>`